# Geometry Nodes: How to rotate 90 degrees around a certain object as the axis of rotation?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry-nodes

I would like to achieve a function that can rotate and duplicate a specified number of objects around a certain reference axis. However, I am encountering an unsolvable problem with regards to how to implement the relative rotation of an object by a specific angle based on the rotational reference axis. Please help me out. Thank you everyone!

In the following image, the object positioned behind is the correct result that I desire.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://blend-exchange.com/b/GRk3RMDB/) what you're after? If so, I'll make an answer out of it.

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely correct! Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can be lazy and avoid doing the maths ourselves.. what seems to be required is a bit of plumbing to adapt between the Euler representation of rotations (blue, vector type sockets) and the internal representation (magenta sockets), which I believe is Quaternion. Then we can use some *Utility > Rotation* nodes as follows:

[image]

You may want the group to modify its own input geometry, and/or decide whether to use 'Original' pr 'Relative' instance imports, for variations on this behaviour:

[image]

[image]